# Calling a R script from Asp.net mvc

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, r, r.net

My target is to call a R function which is saved in the disk, execute that function and show the output to a html page.

And to obtain this I wrote the following code (found somewhere in the net).

```
 public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var rCodeFilePath = @"K:/RPrograms/hello.R";

        var rScriptExecutablePath = @"C:/Program Files/R/R-3.2.2/bin/Rscript.exe";

        string result = string.Empty;

        try
        {

            var info = new ProcessStartInfo();
            info.FileName = rScriptExecutablePath;
            info.WorkingDirectory = Path.GetDirectoryName(rScriptExecutablePath);
            info.Arguments = rCodeFilePath;

            info.RedirectStandardInput = false;
            info.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            info.UseShellExecute = false;
            info.CreateNoWindow = true;

            using (var proc = new Process())
            {
                proc.StartInfo = info;
                proc.Start();
                result = proc.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
                proc.Close();
            }

            ViewBag.Result=result;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new Exception("R Script failed: " + result, ex);
        }

        return View();
    }
```

I dont see any error, but in the "result", I get an empty result. When I run that function in the 'RGui', it show a result.
The R function is basically a hello world code.

Can anybody show some light??

Answer (score 0):

You are sure this is the correct URL? "C:/Program Files/R/R-3.2.2/bin/Rscript.exe"
Try to use your URL to the file like this: C:\Program Files\R\R-3.2.2\bin\Rscript.exe

I'm just suggesting, not sure though.

Goodluck further on.

Comment: If you try to access those programs/directories on your computer, do they actually exist? Sometimes it's just a typo, again I'm not sure.